# How to display RGB instead of HSB in Adobe XD's color picker?

Tags: color, adobe-xd

Our designer has handed me an Adobe XD document. I'm trying to grab RGB values from the elements, but when I bring the color picker I see no option to change to RGB from HSB (I wanted to upload screenshot but due to the current AWS outage imgur is rejecting my upload request).

How can I switch to RGB?

Comment: If you'd like this feature in XD, please upvote https://adobexd.uservoice.com/forums/353007/suggestions/14684583-show-color-rgb-rgba-value

Comment: Although late, switching colour values between hex, rgb and hsb is now available in XD. Designers can also publish the design specs for devs to inspect on an element by element basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can’t currently choose to view colours as RGB in Adobe Experience Design, and you can’t open the macOS system colour picker either.

But, you could copy and paste the HEX into the system picker, and convert to RGB that way. The system picker can be opened in many apps, including TextEdit.

[image: macOS color picker]

If you’re after CSS RGBA values, third party colour pickers can provide that.

[image: Skala Color]